# How to find the largest set of consecutive integers in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I'm looking at a very large set of binary data which is in a separate file. The challenge is to find the largest consecutive number of 1's and 0's. I have already accessed the file from within Python (I'm using Python btw) and have been able to code to find out the total number of 0's and 1's. any help would be much appreciated as I am a total beginner to coding when using Python. Cheers.
This what I've done thus far:

```
filename = "C:/01.txt"
file = open(filename, "r")
count_1 = 0
count_0 = 0

for line in file:
    count_0 = count_0 + line.count("0")
    count_1 = count_1 + line.count("1")
    pass

print("Number of 1s = " + str(count_1))
print("Number of 0s = " + str(count_0))
```

I have not actually started the coding to find the consecutive numbers.

Comment: Can you show us your latest attempt on solving this?

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution: Loop through the data, count consecutive 1s read and when reading a 0 (meaning you reached the end of one segment) compare it's length to the longest segment of consecutive 1s found so far.

```
def getMaxSegmentLength(readable):
    current_length= 0
    max_length= 0

    for x in readable:
        if x == '1':
            current_length+= 1
        else:
            max_length= max(max_length, current_length)
            current_length= 0

    return max(max_length, current_length)


def main():
    # open a file located in G:/input.txt in read mode and name the file object: inputf
    with open('G:/input.txt', 'r') as inputf:

        # put all the text in filef in s
        s= inputf.read()

        # get the longest streak of 1s in string s
        n= getMaxSegmentLength(s)

        print(n)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: would this just be to find the longest streak in the given data in: s = '0110010000011101111'??

Comment: This is a function to find longest streak in a string. Pass the string in your file to get a whole file's longest streak: `getMaxSegmentLength(filename.read())`

Comment: When I put:    def getMaxSegementLength(filename.read()):   -   It tells me that the fullstop is incorrect syntax, and it tells that  -   ',' or '( or )' expected   -  I don't know what this means.

Comment: You do not write `def` when making a function call, it's only needed when defining a function. View my code again, I edited it to get the longest streak from a file.

Answer (score 3):

To find the longest occurrence of a certain substring, you could use a function like this one:

```
def longest_segment(sub, string):
    return max(m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'(%s)\1*' % sub, string))
```

This works by finding all occurrences of the provided substring, `sub`, in the `string`, and returning the longest one.

Answer (score -1):

```
s=raw_input() #read s from file in this case
zero=0
one=0
zz=0
oo=0
for i in list(s):
    if i=='1':
        if zz>=1:
            zero=max(zero,zz)
            zz=0
        oo+=1
    else:
        if oo>=1:
            one=max(one,oo)
            oo=0
        zz+=1
if oo>=1:
    one=max(oo,one)
if zz>=1:
    zero=max(zero,zz)
print zero,one
#O(n)
```

Comment: Please tell what is wrong in the code as it has been downvoted. Thank you.

Comment: Probably because it's rather unclear. `zz` and `oo` are bad variable names, and it looks like you're doing way more work than needed.

Comment: ok. How can I reduce this code? keeping time complexity same.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a good way (I'm not the downvoter btw so I'm just guessing). I think the downvoter probably thinks there's a much better way to do it and this is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Not the DV, but if I were to see this code for the first time without context, it will be unclear for me as to what it even does. I recommend explaining your code, so that it answers the question.